# Is there a PowerShell cmdlet to enable Hyper-V "Enhanced Session Mode Policy"?

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

I am running Hyper-V on a Windows Server 2012 R2 system, which is getting staged via SCCM. Now I am wondering if there is a way to enable enhanced session mode policy using powershell. Unfortunately i cant find anything on technet http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848559.aspx and nothing within "get-command -module hyper-v"

Answer (score 2):

As easy as

```
Set-VMhost -EnableEnhancedSessionMode $TRUE
```